# What is the history behind celebrating Tulsi Vivah?

Tags: practice, tulasi

What is the history behind celebrating Tulsi Vivah and What are the correct ways follows to do the Tulsi Vivah Pujan?

Comment: You mean Tulasi-Saligram vivah?

Comment: yes, I would love to know the history of this as well

Comment: https://iskcondesiretree.com/page/tulasisaligrama-vivaha might be helpful but article uses Vrinda and Jalandhar however it should be Tulasi and Śaṅkhacūḍa as per Shiva Purana ( https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226182.html ), Brahma-vaivarta Purana ( https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.424443/page/n260 ) and their other article ( http://www.iskcontimes.com/archive/tulasi-saligrama-vivaha )...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this article, please give an answer  @YDS